# An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Hangfire.AspNetCore.dll

Tags: c#, hangfire, .net-core-2.1

I have asp.net core 2.1 application with Hangfire 1.6.2 and Hangfire.MySql.NetCore 1.0.7. There is one job that when it is enqueued for the thirth or fourth time, the application throws this exception and shuts down; `An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Hangfire.AspNetCore.dll` at the moment it is being enqueued. Other background jobs also follow this pattern. The jobs are successfully enqueued and the exception gets thrown when the job is being activated to the processing queue. Here is a log which appears right before the exception is thrown and this is the same time when the job is being activated. This hints some problems with distributed locking;

```
Hangfire.MySql.MySqlDistributedLock:Trace: MySqlDistributedLock resource=JobQueue, timeout=00:00:30
Hangfire.MySql.MySqlDistributedLock:Trace: Release resource=JobQueue
Hangfire.MySql.MySqlDistributedLock:Trace: MySqlDistributedLock resource=job:16:state-lock, timeout=00:15:00
Hangfire.MySql.MySqlDistributedLock:Trace: Acquire resource=job:16:state-lock, timeout=00:15:00
Hangfire.MySql.MySqlWriteOnlyTransaction:Trace: SetJobState jobId=16
Hangfire.MySql.MySqlWriteOnlyTransaction:Trace: PersistJob jobId=16
Hangfire.MySql.MySqlDistributedLock:Trace: Release resource=job:16:state-lock
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Hangfire.AspNetCore.dll
```

After restart I go to the hanfire dashboard and see the job stuck in 'processing' status
[image]

Answer (score -1):

From the package manager console, please run this command:

```
Install-Package HangFire.Core -Version 1.6.21
```

Comment: Why are you recommending this anyway? Is there some known bug to the previous version ?

Comment: Reinstalling package may solve the problem. It is a trial. I faced a problem with this package "HangFire.Core", once using the above command line, found that the problem fixed.